# Import/export CDA documents

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, hl7, cda

I'm working on a project that imports/exports CDA documents. I can't find any good parser/library in ruby on rails or javascript that reads the CDA (XML) and returns different sections. Any idea what is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

As you stated yourself: CDA is all XML. Just use your favourite XML-library and use XPATH to access the elements/attributes you are interested in.